# How to use pageList in a view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagedlist

I am trying to use PagedList to obtain a paged list of some tickets.

The model i am using is the following :

```
public class TicketIndexModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Ticket> ticketList { get; set; }
    public string TicketTitle { get; set; }
    public string TicketDescription { get; set; }
}
```

and in the controller i am sending to the view :

```
TicketIndexModel indexTicketList = new TicketIndexModel();
indexTicketList.ticketList = db.Tickets.Where(r => r.UserName == currentUserName).ToList().OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated);
return View(indexTicketList.ticketList.ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize));
```

In the view i have 2 things, a list of all the tickets and a simple form to add another ticket. Here is a little code :

```
@model PagedList.IPagedList<CDS.Models.TicketIndexModel>
@foreach (var row in Model)
{
    foreach(var item in row.ticketList){
// the list of tickets
}
}
```

But my problem is in the form for adding a new ticket

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.TicketTitle)
```

model.TicketTitle is not available to access.

How can i fix this ? Or do you suggest i use a different paging system ?

**EDIT :**

I made the changes you said in the controller, switched to a TicketIndexModel in the view, changed my model to use an IPagedList.

I  also added the following code :
    
    Page @(Model.PageCount < Model.PageNumber ? 0 : Model.PageNumber)
    of @Model.PageCount

```
@if (Model.HasPreviousPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("<<", "Index", new { page = 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink("< Prev", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber - 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
}
else
{
    @:<<
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @:< Prev
}

@if (Model.HasNextPage)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Next >", "Index", new { page = Model.PageNumber + 1, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
    @Html.Raw(" ");
    @Html.ActionLink(">>", "Index", new { page = Model.PageCount, sortOrder = ViewBag.CurrentSort, currentFilter=ViewBag.CurrentFilter  })
}
else
{
    @:Next >
    @Html.Raw(" ")
    @:>>
}
```

But now i get this error
Models.TicketIndexModel' does not contain a definition for 'PageCount' and no extension method 'PageCount' accepting a first argument of type 'Models.TicketIndexModel' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Should i change the model ? I don't know what to do exactly, it's the first time i use this, and i only started using MVC 3 months ago.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In the view i have 2 things, a list of all the tickets and a simple
>   form to add another ticket.

Then `IPagedList<CDS.Models.TicketIndexModel>` is not a suitable view model for this view since you need more information in it than just a simple paged list of tickets.

You could make this view strongly typed to the `TicketIndexModel` type instead:

```
TicketIndexModel indexTicketList = new TicketIndexModel();
indexTicketList.ticketList = db
    .Tickets
    .Where(r => r.UserName == currentUserName)
    .ToList()
    .OrderByDescending(r => r.DateCreated)
    .ToPagedList(pageNumber,pageSize);
return View(indexTicketList);
```

and your view:

```
@model TicketIndexModel
...
Here you can access Model.TicketTitle since you need it and Model.ticketList to show your list
```

Of course you might need to adapt the model so that it uses an `IPagedList<Ticket>` instead of `IEnumerable<Ticket>`.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I edited my first post, please take a loot now.

Comment: In your view you should use `Model.ticketList.PageNumber` and `Model.ticketList.PageCount` instead.